# Proper database design for Big Data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, bigdata

I have a huge number of tables for each country. I want multiple comment related fields for each so that users can make comments on my website. I might might have a few more fields like: date when comment was created, user_id of commenter. Also I might need to add other fields in the future.For Example, company_support_comment/support_rating, company_professionalism_comment

Let's say I have 1 million companies in one table and 100 comments per company. then I get lot's of comments just for one country It will easily exceed 2 billion.
Unsigned bigint can support 18 446 744 073 709 551 615. So we can have that many comments in one table. Unsigned int will give us 4.2+ billion. Which won't be enough in one table.
However imagine querying a table with 4 billion records? How long would that take ? I might not be able to efficiently retrieve the comments and it would take a huge load on the database. Given that in practice one table probably can't be done. 
Multiple tables might also be bad. unless we just use json data..

Actually I'm not sure now. I need a proper solution for my database design. I am using mysql now.

Comment: Have you thought about using a NoSQL data store like Cassandra?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I never used NoSQL. It will be wise to use NoSQL data store like Cassandra, right ?

Comment: If you are really talking about billions of records, traditional SQL might become a limitation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So, what should be the proper approach please ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question goes in the wrong direction, in my view.

Start with your database design.  That means go with bigints to start with if you are concerned about it (because converting from int to bigint is a pain if you get that wrong).  Build a good, normalized schema.  Then figure out how to make it fast.

In your case, PostgreSQL may be a better option than MySQL because your query is going to likely be against secondary indexes.  These are more expensive on MySQL with InnoDB than PostgreSQL, because with MySQL, you have to traverse the primary key index to retrieve the row.  This means, effectively, traversing two btree indexes to get the rows you are looking for.  Probably not the end of the world, but if performance is your primary concern that may be a cost you don't want to pay.  While MySQL covering indexes are a little more useful in some cases, I don't think they help you here since you are interested, really, in text fields which you probably are not directly indexing.

In PostgreSQL, you have a btree index which then gives you a series of page/tuple tuples, which then allow you to look up the data effectively with random access.  This would be a win with such a large table, and my experience is that PostgreSQL can perform very well on large tables (tables spanning, say, 2-3TB in size with their indexes).

However, assuming you stick with MySQL, careful attention to indexing will likely get you where you need to go.  Remember you are only pulling up 100 comments for a company and traversing an index has O(log n) complexity so it isn't really that bad.  The biggest issue is traversing the pkey index for each of the rows retrieved but even that should be manageable.

Comment: MySQL's B+Trees are not that bad, and doesn't Postgres have a downside in its implementation?

Comment: The big downside in the Pg implementation is that a Pkey lookup requires more random disk I/O.  So the tradeoff is between something optimized for pkey lookups (the InnoDB tables are index oriented) and the more generally optimized approach of PostgreSQL.  So yes, there are downsides, but don't think they apply to *this* use case.

Comment: Also as I noted, even the double index traversal isn't that bad, but it is a cost.  B+ trees help you in some cases (and PostgreSQL does allow b+ trees via GiST).

Answer (score 1):

4 billions records in one table is not a big deal for No SQL database. Even for traditional database, if you build a bunch of secondary indexes correctly, like in MySQL, search in them will be quick(travels a b tree like data structure takes Log(n) disk visitation).

And for faster access, you need a front end cache system to work on your hot data, like redis or memcachd.

Recall your current situation, you are not sure what fields will be needed, then the only choice is a no-sql solution. Since the fields(columns) can be added in the future when they will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

(From a MySQL perspective...)

1 table for companies; `INT UNSIGNED` will do.  1 table for comments `BIGINT UNSIGNED` may be necessary.  You won't fetch hundreds of comments for display at once, will you?  Unless you take care of the data layout, 100 comments could easily be 100 random disk hits, which (on cheap disk) would be 1 second.

You must have indexes (this mostly rules out NoSql)?  Otherwise searching for records would be too painfully slow.

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (
    comment_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    company_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ts TIMESTAMP,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(company_id, comment_id, ts), -- to get clustering and ordering
    INDEX(comment_id)  -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If you paginate the display of the comments, use the tips in [remember where you left off](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).  That will make fetching comments about as efficient as possible.

As for Log(n) -- With about 100 items per node, a billion rows will have only 5 levels of BTree.  This is small enough to essentially ignore when worrying about timing.  `Comments` will be a terabyte or more?  And your RAM will be significantly less than that?  Then, you will *generally* have non-leaf nodes cached, but leaf nodes (where the data is) not cached.  There might be several comment rows per leaf node consecutively stored.  Hence, less than 100 disk hits to get 100 comments for display.

(Note:  When the data is much bigger than RAM, 'performance' degenerates into 'counting the disk hits'.)

Well, you mentioned comments.  What about other queries?

As for "company_support_comment/support_rating..." -- The simplest would be to add a new table(s) when you need to add those 'columns'.  The basic Company data is relatively bulky and static; ratings are relative small but frequently changing.  (Again, I am 'counting the disk hits'.)